# Get the number of gunicorn workers?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

How can I programmatically retrieve the current number of Gunicorn workers from within a WSGI app running in Gunicorn?  I'm using Flask if that makes any difference.

Comment: you could store the number of workers to run in an env variable. You could use that to start gunicorn and access it from python

Answer (score 12):

From terminal:

```
ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

`gunicorn` could be the app name if that is present in the command (if you're running just one app this example would work fine, else it would show the total amount of workers of all apps)

Comment: I'm trying to get the number from within python (your solution includes the master process which gives one too many; and there may be more than one gunicorn app running anyway).

Comment: @DoctorJ That's why I suggest to grep something like the app name. If you need it in Python, use an environment variable instead.